# CS193P - Assignment 3 - drawRect get called only on the first setNeedsDisplay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cs193p

I'm taking CS193P iPhone Development courses, and even if.. I know that I'm pretty late 
comparing to Stanford's students, I'm doing Assignment 3.

My current problem is: My drawRect method does not get called on every 
setNeedsDisplay... but only on the first.

Also, what I noted is that my polygon object is NULL (from 
PolygonView).

Here are the sources of my project:

PolygonShape.h 
http://pastie.org/855503

PolygonShape.m 
http://pastie.org/855507

Controller.h 
http://pastie.org/855508

Controller.m 
http://pastie.org/855509

PolygonView.h 
http://pastie.org/855511

PolygonView.m 
http://pastie.org/855513

If someone could help me.. I guess this is pretty simple but I can't 
seem to find it!

Thanks a LOT! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawRect:` is not necessarily called on every `setNeedsDisplay`.

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` only clear the cache of the view's layer. `drawRect:` will be called only when the screen is actually refreshed. So before the runloop resumes calling `setNeedsDisplay` multiple times may not have any effects.